# Stop agent walking off the grid (grid world example of RL)

Tags: java, agent, gridworld

My Problem is when my agent gets to 0,0 , 0,9 etc i am trying to stop it from going to 9,0, or 9,9 etc
like this in this example

```
   (0,0) N -1.0 (9,0)
   (9,0) N -1.0 (8,0)
   (8,0) W -1.0 (8,9)
```

I want it to move in-between the gird and not take short by going back around the grid. Eg, instead of goind form (0,0) to (9,0) go to (0,1) 0r (1 ,0) etc.

I tried something simple like this code, to check if the x and y values are greater than the x and y values for number of rows and columns  or if x and y is less than 0

```
  public boolean Notvalid(int x, int y) {

    return (x > cr.NUM_ROWS || y > cr.NUM_COLUMNS || x < 0 || y < 0);

     }
```

and call this method when setting the x and y co-ordinates

```
 public GridState(int xpos, int ypos) {

    if (!Notvalid(x, y)) {

        x = xpos;
        y = ypos;

    } else {
        x = cr.START_ROW;
        y = cr.START_COL;
    }
}
```

Anybody know an easier way to handle a rule like this?

Comment: Is `cr.NUM_ROWS` 9 or 10? It seems column indices are from 0 to 9, so `cr.NUM_ROWS` should be 10, but then you should use `x >= cr.NUM_ROWS` or `x > cr.NUM_ROWS - 1`

Comment: Also, it seems like you are checking whether the _current_ x/y position is valid (`x` and `y`), and not the position where the agent is to go (`xpos`, `ypos`). Also, by setting `x = cr.START_ROW`, aren't you exactly doing what you do not want to do, i.e. set the agent to `0` when it goes to `10`? However, all of this is just a guess without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Hi  @tobias_k thank you for pointing out that i was passing in the wrong variables ,You were right i was doing the opposite of what i want to do.  i did not notices it. It now works as intended. Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are three problems with your code:

- Assuming that row indices are `0` to `9` and `cr.NUM_ROWS` is `10`, you should use `x >= cr.NUM_ROWS` or `x > cr.NUM_ROWS - 1` instead of `x > cr.NUM_ROWS`. (same for columns)
- You are checking whether the *current* x/y position is valid (`x` and `y`), and not the position where the agent is about to go (`xpos`, `ypos`).
- By setting `x = cr.START_ROW`, it seems like you are exactly doing what you do not want to do, i.e. set the agent to `0` when it goes to `10`.

Try this:

```
public boolean notValid(int x, int y) {
    return x >= cr.NUM_ROWS || y >= cr.NUM_COLUMNS || x < 0 || y < 0;
}

public gridState(int xpos, int ypos) {
    if (! notvalid(xpos, ypos)) {
        x = xpos;
        y = ypos;
    } else {
        // new position not valid -> just stay where you are
    }
}
```